# The situation in nazi Germany of a Jewish male married to an "aryan" female vs Jewish female married to an "aryan" male?

Tags: nazi-germany, jews, race

For some reason, most of what I have read deals with Jewish males who were married to "aryan" females. This might be because the other way around, the female would have converted to Christianity more frequently, but I wonder if the nazi state saw something fundamentally different about an aryan male marrying a Jewish female than the other way around. The [protest on Rosenstrasse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosenstrasse_protest) was afaik uniformly Jewish males being held and non-Jewish wives protesting their imprisonment — why was there not a single case even in this protest of a Jewish wife being imprisoned? (Unless of course there was.)

The only memoir I am aware of, [Klemperer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Victor_Klemperer)'s, describes the difficult but survivable situation of a Jewish male married to a non-Jewish wife; I do not know if any female Jews wrote memoirs.

It is in general a counterintuitive situation: one would have thought that in a racist dictatorship, beyond merely encouraging divorce, it would have been mandated in almost all cases and, not to give nazis ideas retroactively, the aryan partners who were now single might have been "matched."

In fact, this idea sounds so much like something nazis would do it makes me wonder if the predominant case in most mixed marriages was that the male was Jewish; that for some reason very few Jewish females married non-Jews.

EDIT: Jan's link in the comments basically explains that mixed marriages did indeed tend to have a Jewish male most of the time: https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosenstra%C3%9Fen-Protest

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133372/discussion-on-question-by-releseabe-the-situation-in-nazi-germany-of-a-jewish-ma).  Comments must remain civil.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Nuremberg laws do not make a distinction . Full blooded German (male or female) would remain full blooded German. For Mischling, he or she could be considered full Jew if he or she is married to a Jew. No distinctions was made in regards of gender. Btw, there was a well known protest of German wives married to Jews, demanding to release them :  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosenstrasse_protest

Comment: @rs.29: I am not saying laws made a distinction by gender; but somehow it appears that most mixed marriages had a Jewish male and non-Jewish female which is why the protest you mention (this protest made the question occur to me) had uniformly female protestors afaik -- I wondered why some of the protestors could not be males hoping to help their Jewish wives. A comment indicated that cultural differences made it more likely for a Jewish male to marry a non-Jewish female than the other way around.

Comment: I think you have to seriously read up about what national socialism is and does. Nitpicking or fantasying impossible scenarios won't do any good. A German man or woman married to a Jew (of either sex) was in BIG trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The [protest on Rosenstrasse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosenstrasse_protest) was afaik uniformly Jewish males being held and non-Jewish wives protesting their imprisonment — why was there not a single case even in this protest of a Jewish wife being imprisoned? (Unless of course there was.)

Maybe five to ten percent ("a bit more than hundred women among a lot more than thousand men") of those imprisoned in Rosenstraße were women, according to a footnote in [this paper](http://upgr.bv-opfer-ns-militaerjustiz.de/uploads/Dateien/Veranstaltungen/gruner-fabrikaktion.pdf) by Wolf Gruner (Wolf Gruner: Die Fabrik-Aktion und die Ereignisse in der Berliner Rosenstraße: Fakten und Fiktionen um den 27. Februar 1943. In: Jahrbuch für Antisemitismusforschung 11 (2002), p. 137–177):

> Selbst wenn weniger Frauen als Männer aus „Mischehen“ in der Industrie tätig waren, da sie öfter als „privilegiert“ eingestuft wurden, ist der geringe Anteil von wenig mehr als hundert Frauen bei weit mehr als tausend Männern nicht schlüssig.

(footnote 130 on p.162)

Gruner rejects the notion that what happened at Rosenstraße was a mass protest in the way that is sometimes depicted in the media, but he also points out that men participated and gives a hint why there were few male participants (emphasis mine):

> Es warteten dort auch Männer, einige sogar in
> Uniform.

> There were also men waiting there, **some even in uniform**.

(p.169)

Those held in Rosenstraße in March 1943 had been rounded up in Berlin during the [Fabrikaktion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fabrikaktion) on February 27th (which was a Germany-wide roundup of Jewish forced labour workers). Note that not *all* Jewish spouses from mixed marriages in Berlin were rounded up during the Fabrikaktion, and of those who had been rounded up, not all were imprisoned in Rosenstraße. One tragic example [here](https://www.stolpersteine-berlin.de/de/biografie/7034). Gruner implies that the share of women among Jewish spouses in mixed marriages in Berlin was actually considerably higher than five to ten percent.

---

> it makes me wonder if the predominant case in most mixed marriages was that the male was Jewish

Yes, according to [wikipedia](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mischehe_(Nationalsozialismus)), in about three in four mixed marriages, the husband was Jewish. Some well-known counterexamples were [Heinz Rühmann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heinz_R%C3%BChmann) (divorced in 1938), [Veit Harlan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Veit_Harlan)(!) (in the 1920s), [Joachim Gottschalk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joachim_Gottschalk) (suicide in 1941). [Hans Albers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hans_Albers) was not married, but in a long-running relationship.

---

> one would have thought that in a racist dictatorship, beyond merely encouraging divorce, it would have been mandated in almost all cases

This was actually [under discussion](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mischehe_(Nationalsozialismus)) again and again, but (due to expected opposition from the church?) it was never implemented. Jewish spouses from mixed marriages were actually in some instances [deported and killed](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenny_Grimminger) anyway. And starting in early 1945 all Jews from mixed marriages were supposed to be deported to [Theresienstadt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theresienstadt_Ghetto).

Comment: Thanks for this. I know that the church varied in its response, sometimes taking the racist stance (expelling or making it difficult for members of Jewish ancestry to worship in churches) and other times I guess protecting "racially" Jewish converts. My sense is that had there been a nazi victory things would have been grim indeed for any part-Jews or mixed marriages; in the former case, probably sterilization just to get rid of Jewish characteristics for good, and for Jews in mixed marriages, forced divorce and sent to camps or maybe again sterilization.